# Adding csv files multiple times into Google colab

Tags: python-3.x

I have uploaded two CSV files onto colab.I have extracted one file using code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(" pasted file path here")
df 
the code worked!
now I wanted to open another CSV file.
df2 = pd.read_csv("pasted another file path here")
df2
```

now, I'm getting errors like below
**'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 87247: invalid start byte**

how to solve this

Comment: Can you post an example of csv file that is giving error? Specially the line where the problem occurs. Looks like the csv is using another encoding as utf8 and error message is self explainatory.